# How to turn on the player’s main camera after turning it

Tags: c#, unreal-engine4

There is a player on the scene and a camera (not the player’s camera), which I switch to in order to play the animation of how the player gets out of bed. When the animation ends, I want to return the player’s camera, but for some reason it’s in the middle of the player’s capsule, and not at eye level where the camera itself is.

It’s not clear to me what the player’s initial object is. In theory, you need to pass a UCameraComponent, not an APlayerController, to SetViewTarget, but then it generates the error "no suitable conversion function from" UCameraComponent "to" AActor * "exists"

And I have a widget that displays descriptions of objects if you hover over them. For some reason, it turns off after using the code below

.h

```
UPROPERTY() APlayerController* player;
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) AActor* cameraPlayerWakeUp;

// What else I've tried:
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) UCameraComponent* playerCameraComponent;
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) ACharacter* character;
FORCEINLINE ACharacter* GetCharacter() const { return character; }
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere) APawn* playerPawn;
```

.cpp

```
void AAct_31::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    player = UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerController(this, 0);
}

     void AAct_31::GameCicle()
     {
       player->SetViewTarget(cameraPlayerWakeUp);

       //.. animation of awakening

       // What I've tried to set up camera:
       player->SetViewTarget(player);
       player->SetViewTarget(playerCameraComponent);
       player->SetViewTarget(character);
       player->SetViewTarget(playerPawn);
     }
```

[image]

Comment: Try to `SetViewTarget` to the player's pawn, not the playercontroller.

Comment: @Rotem You mean like this `player->SetViewTarget(player->GetPawn());`? The engine is crashes with this code

Comment: Likely there's no pawn assigned